# treeview problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, navigateurl

have a treeview control in ASP.NET and C#.

Root node            (This is fixed)

---Parent Node 1    ( Parent node and child are populated from the database directly. )

----Child node1

----Child node2

---Parent node 2

Now When a value is added to a database it get added in the treeview. 
I cannot get a way to select the parent and child node and make it perform a function like go to another page or something...

I have the code to retrieve values from the database and display on the treenode dynamically.
Just the selection is a problem.

If there is a tutorial of any other information please let me know

Comment: Post your markup and code behind.

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SumooHAgentDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [MachineGroupName], [MachineGroupID] FROM [MachineGroups]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView2" runat="server"  ontreenodepopulate="TreeView2_TreeNodePopulate">
            <Nodes>
                <asp:TreeNode PopulateOnDemand="True" Text="Machine Group" 
                    Value="Machine Group" NavigateUrl="~/Gridviewpage.aspx"></asp:TreeNode>
            </Nodes>
        </asp:TreeView>

Comment: protected void TreeView2_TreeNodePopulate(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Node.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
            {
                switch (e.Node.Depth)
                {
                    case 0:
                        PopulateMachineGroups(e.Node);
                            break;
                    case 1:
                            PopulateMachines(e.Node);
                            break;

Comment: protected void PopulateMachines(TreeNode node)
{
SqlCommand sqlQuery = new SqlCommand();
sqlQuery.CommandText = "Select MachineName From Machines " +" Where MachineGroupID = @machinegrpid";
sqlQuery.Parameters.Add("@machinegrpid", SqlDbType.Int).Value=node.Value;
DataSet ResultSet = RunQuery(sqlQuery);
if (ResultSet.Tables.Count > 0)
{
foreach (DataRow row in ResultSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
TreeNode NewNode = new
TreeNode(row["MachineName"].ToString());
NewNode.PopulateOnDemand = false;
NewNode.SelectAction =TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
node.ChildNodes.Add(NewNode);
}
}
}

Comment: 1st box is the aspx page
2nd box is how i switch
3rd box is to populate the tree
so the tree should look like 

machinegroup    (root)
--machines1     (parent)
----pc1         (child)
----pc2

where the parent and child are in two different tables

Comment: Can edit the question and add your code? It's tough to read when it's run together in the comments.

Comment: what you want acheive in the selection? do you want to show checkboxes along with the node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is to go to another page where you adding your new treenode, you need to set navigateURL property

```
NewNode.NavigateUrl = "yourURL";
```

Comment: this worked if you are sending all the child nodes or parent nodes to the respective pages but i wanted to know which node is getting selected also.

I was able to do this by sending the value in the navigation URl itself :
NewNode.NavigateUrl = "~/WebForm4.aspx?node=" + NewNode.Text;

then you have to add a query string at the page you navigate to, in order to vetch the value you just passed.

Thanks.